# TFS 2017 WITD Import error VS403073

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

While importing a newly customized Work Item Type Definition into TFS 2017.3, I am receiving the error:

> VS403073: Group {GroupName} violates the rule that a group can only
>   contain a single HTML or WebPage control preceded by label controls.

My question is three-fold:

1) Where are these styling/schema rules documented?  I was unable to find any information on this, or any other schema rule, on Microsoft's site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/weblayout-xml-elements?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json#weblayout-element-syntax).

2) I am trying to keep several FieldControls and a single HTMLFieldControl grouped together under one heading on the WebForm for organization purposes.  Why would there be a rule put in place to prevent this type of organization?

3) Is it possible to, and what would be the consequences of, bypassing this rule and importing the WITD anyway?

Please let me know if any further information/clarification is needed.

Edit:
Psudo code would be something to this effect:

```
<WebLayout>
...
  <Page>
    <Section>
      <Group Label="Group 1">
        <Control type="FieldControl" Label="G1C1" FieldName="X.G1Field1" />
        <Control type="FieldControl" Label="G1C2" FieldName="X.G1Field2" />
        <Control type="FieldControl" Label="G1C3" FieldName="X.G1Field3" />
        <Control type="HTMLFieldControl" Label="G1C4" FieldName="X.G1Field4" />
      </Group>
    </Section>
  </Page>
</WebLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share your customized Work Item Type Definition?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well.  I moved the HTMLFieldControl to its own group and that resolved the issue.

#### Example from Microsoft's documentation

**Error:**

```
<Section>
    <Group Label="Description:">
        <Control Label="Reason For Request:" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="System.Description" />
        <Control Label="Business Case For Request:" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="MB.BusinessCase" />
    </Group>
</Section>
```

**Resolution:**

```
<Section>
    <Group Label="Reason for Request">
        <Control Label="Reason For Request:" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="System.Description" />       
    </Group>
    <Group Label="Business Case">
        <Control Label="Business Case For Request" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="Custom.BusinessCase" />       
    </Group>
</Section>
```

Documentation can be found [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/resolve-errors?view=azure-devops#vs403073-group--group-name-violates-the-rule-that-a-group-can-only-contain-a-single-html-or-webpage-control-preceded-by-label-controls)